# How do install couchdb on OSX Leopard

Tags: macos, couchdb

I run Mac OS X 10.5.8. I would like to be able to run couchdb but I am having some difficulty and I wonder if anyone can help. I would rather not use homebrew unless its the only way and its known to work as I use mac ports for most of my installs at the momemnt. If its the only way, then so be it.

I have tried several different ways to do it and I am afraid I don't have all the error messages from them.

```
port install couchdb
```

ran, but didn't appear to run a couchdb demon.

```
port install couchdb-devel
```

install crashed complaining that erlang may not have been built with ssl

The couchbase server binaries (1.1.1 and 1.1) give an error:

```
unknown required load command 0x80000022
```

Downloading apache-couchdb-1.0.2 source and running

```
./configure
make
```

Produces a binary that appears not to run properly:

```
sh-3.2# ./bin/couchdb  
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{couch,start,[]},{init,start_it,1},{init,start_em,1}]}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

which I assume is not the correct behaviour. I wanted to test before I did a make install, which may have been the wrong thing to do.

Does anyone have known to work solution or can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: although the community here can answer this question, the place of the question is in super user

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't quite sure where the line was. I will try there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strongly recommend installing [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and using that to install couchdb. Homebrew is a 'package manager' that really is a joy to use. Once installed, `brew install couchdb` is enough to get a working installation.

**EDIT:** I should have re-read your question; I missed your mention of homebrew. Feel free to ignore this answer.

A quick look at http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_OSX suggests that `sudo port install erlang +ssl` then `sudo port install couchdb` might help? It would seem that +ssl would force compilation with ssl. Worth a try.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I gave up and tried using homebrew (I moved old /usr/local stuff out the way temporarily). I followed the instructions on the apache wiki. It installed fine (at least it succeeded - I'm hoping that equals "fine" for homebrew). If I run couchdb from the command line it runs but nothing is listening to 5984. The pid file is there but is empty and there is nothing in the var/log/couchdb directory. Any thoughts?

Comment: It is running 3 processes (two couchdb and one erlang).

Comment: Thanks. Homebrew turned out to fix the problem, but first I had to uninstall the erlang port. The problem with homebrew was it was picking up erlang in /opt rather than /usr/local but deinstalling the other erlang fixed the problem. So that's fine. Next time I do this I'll try the +ssl option on mac ports erlang.